# The mutated value get not updated in a function of struct that use that value in Swift/SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a custom struct called **CustomType**, this struct has only one variable called **value** type `Bool`. I am mutating `value` with struct functions, after mutating of `value` I print it, to be sure if I actually done it! And It works! but there is another function called `dispatchQueueFuction` which the value get not updated there! this function has a safety before using `DispatchQueue` but for unknown reason for my `value` is not updated there! why? and how can I solve this issue that the `dispatchQueueFuction` could be able see and understand the newValue of `value`.

***PS: I tried anything that I know, for example I created a computed property for being sure that we are reading the right value! but did not help! a wired issue for me!***

```
struct CustomType {
    
    var value: Bool = Bool()
    
    var getValue: Bool {
        
        get { return self.value }
        
    }

    mutating func start() {
        
        self.value = true; print("self.value =", value)
        
        dispatchQueueFuction(value: self.getValue)
        
    }
    
    func dispatchQueueFuction(value: Bool) {
        
        if self.getValue {

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                
                print("Hello, World!")
                
                dispatchQueueFuction(value: self.getValue)
                
            }
            
        }
  
    }
    
    mutating func stop() { self.value = false; print("self.value =", value) }

}
```

use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var customType: CustomType = CustomType()
    
    var body: some View {

        Button("start") { customType.start() }.padding()
        
        Button("stop") { customType.stop() }.padding()
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: When I tap on stop Button from ContentView, the value should became `false`, right? And it is working but the false value is still true for `dispatchQueueFuction`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`, you're capturing a copy of `self` at the point that it's called. You then keep calling it with new copies of that original value. None of these are related to the value that ContentView holds (since they're copies, not references). If you want to share state, you need a reference type (a class).

`mutating` means "replaces the target value with a brand new, mutated value." It doesn't mean "copies of this value will be updated." A struct is a value type, not a reference type.

Comment: I know the Class would be better fit here, but I am trying to find answer for issue not changing it to class. I already have the working form of class, my goal is struct.

Comment: You cannot do what you're describing with a struct (without having the struct wrap a reference type). The whole point of a struct is that modifications to one copy do not modify another. If you made the `value` property of CustomType a class, then you could do what you're talking about (it's very unswifty design, but it would work).

Comment: Ok, how can I kill that first `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` that got captured?

Comment: By passing it a reference type, or a struct that wraps a reference type. There's no way to do what you're describing with pure value types. They intentionally make independent copies.

Comment: So if I cannot kill it with value type! then I am interested to "or a struct that wraps a reference type" could you give a hint for me, like I should create a class which hold `value: Bool` then I should make an instance of it in my `CustomType` as reference type?

Comment: Correct. If `value` were a class that wraps a Bool, then modifying `value.boolValue` would be seen by all copies of CustomType. This would be terrible Swift (because it would be very confusing to anyone reading it), but it would be legal and work. You would no longer technically need "mutating", and you would still need to worry about thread-safety on the calls to start/stop.

Comment: Note that in SwiftUI there is no promise about when ContentView gets created. Many copies of it may exist, and they may be created at any time (and are). So you should expect many copies of CustomType in different states. This probably is not what you mean. Instead, CustomType should generally be some shared instance (or something passed into the View), but that means it would be a reference type again. This whole approach is broken; you can hack your way around it but it's still broken.

Comment: It worked, thanks for hint and your answer. Is it wired or bad idea using class inside struct? Also now it is working! You said it is broken even it is working! you mean I should use class form of it completely? and I should forget struct form of it even it is working? because of copy issue?

Comment: The point of a value type (struct) is that it doesn't share state. Putting a publicly-available reference type (shared state) inside of that is a bad idea. It works, but it breaks the model (like having a `count` property, but it's negative. It's totally legal, but, huh?). If you want to share state, make CustomType be a class.

Comment: Thanks for all, I would use class form for sure.